# How do you make a functor instance of Matrix and Vector from hmatrix library?

Tags: haskell

Both `Matrix` and `Vector` constructor has kind `*->*`, so they look like value constructors. But when I try something like

```
instance Functor Vector a where
    fmap g ( Vector a ) = Vector ( g a )
```

I get this error:

```
 Not in scope: data constructor `Vector'
```

which makes sense since I can't make a vector by using `let v = Vector [1..3]` anyways. 
But checking the source I see that both Matrix and Vector constructor are exported from their respective modules:

```
Vector.hs
module Data.Packed.Vector (
    Vector,
    fromList, (|>), toList, buildVecto.. 
) where

Matrix.hs

module Data.Packed.Matrix (
    Element,
    Matrix,rows,cols...
) where
```

Dido for applicative functor, monad, etc.

Comment: Usually for a library as mature as hmatrix, if the library doesn't support a common typeclass, the author will have decided that supporting the typeclass would promote use-cases that aren't recommend - e.g for data structures stored as foreign c arrays a type changing `fmap` might cause serious performance problems. In this case however, Vector has the `mapVector` operation which matches `fmap` so it's curious that there is no Functor instance.

Comment: Ah thanks for the comment, I had that question in mind too so thanks for making a note of it

Comment: `mapMatrix` and `mapVector` require `Storable` instances on both input and output, but `fmap` does not; so `Matrix` and `Vector` cannot implement `Functor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Data.Packed.Vector (
    Vector,
    fromList, (|>), toList, buildVecto.. 
) where
```

This exposes the type Vector, but not any of it's constructors.

Your instance declaration corrected:

```
instance Functor Vector where
    fmap  = V.map
```

(assuming you `import Vector as V`, and further assuming you're talking about the Vector from the vector package).

---

**EDIT**: Sorry, didn't see you mentioned the package name. For hmatrix Vectors, it would be mapVector instead of V.map.

**EDIT_ 2**: As mentioned by the others, for hmatrix this won't work because Matrix and Vector require `Storeable` for their content.

Comment: awesome turnaround time. Btw, how big is the performance penalty of converting from matrix to vector, and back?

Comment: @user1128571 No idea. Look at the source code or ask one of the maintainers of that package if they have the time, I didn't see the info on hackage.

Comment: There is no performance penalty, the data array is not changed.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect.  As pointed out by @ConradParker, there is a `Storable` constraint on the Vector version.  So the `instance Functor Vector where` declaration will not compile.  See @AlbertoRuiz's answer.

Answer (score 6):

As [Conrad Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744300/conrad-parker) said, we need `Storable` instances.

Using recent ghc extensions we can define a more general Functor':

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Foreign.Storable(Storable)
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Functor' c where
  type Ok c u v :: Constraint
  type Ok c u v = ()

  fmap' :: Ok c u v => (u -> v) -> c u -> c v

instance Functor' Vector where
  type Ok Vector u v = (Storable u, Storable v)
  fmap' = mapVector
```