# What is the Haskell / hmatrix equivalent of the MATLAB pos function?

Tags: matlab, haskell, hmatrix

I'm translating some MATLAB code to Haskell using the hmatrix library. It's going well, but
I'm stumbling on the pos function, because I don't know what it does or what it's Haskell equivalent will be.

The MATLAB code looks like this:

```
[U,S,V] = svd(Y,0);
diagS = diag(S);
...
A = U * diag(pos(diagS-tau)) * V';
E = sign(Y) .* pos( abs(Y) - lambda*tau );
M = D - A - E;
```

My Haskell translation so far:

```
(u,s,v) = svd y
diagS = diag s
a = u `multiply` (diagS - tau) `multiply` v
```

This actually type checks ok, but of course, I'm missing the "pos" call, and it throws the error:

```
inconsistent dimensions in matrix product (3,3) x (4,4)
```

So I'm guessing pos does something with matrix size? Googling "matlab pos function" didn't turn up anything useful, so any pointers are very much appreciated! (Obviously I don't know much MATLAB)

Incidentally this is for the TILT algorithm to recover low rank textures from a noisy, warped image. I'm very excited about it, even if the math is way beyond me!

Looks like the pos function is defined in a different MATLAB file:

```
function P = pos(A)
P = A .* double( A > 0 );
```

I can't quite decipher what this is doing. Assuming that boolean values cast to doubles where "True" == 1.0 and "False" == 0.0

In that case it turns negative values to zero and leaves positive numbers unchanged?

Comment: Is it possible that `pos` is defined elsewhere in the matlab source?

Comment: Thank you @DanielWagner, that's exactly the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though `pos` finds the positive part of a matrix. You could implement this directly with `mapMatrix`

```
pos :: (Storable a, Num a) => Matrix a -> Matrix a
pos = mapMatrix go where
  go x | x > 0     = x
       | otherwise = 0
```

Though Matlab makes no distinction between `Matrix` and `Vector` unlike Haskell.

But it's worth analyzing that Matlab fragment more. Per http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html the first line computes the "economy-sized" Singular Value Decomposition of `Y`, i.e. three matrices such that

```
U * S * V = Y
```

where, assuming `Y` is `m x n` then `U` is `m x n`, `S` is `n x n` and diagonal, and `V` is `n x n`. Further, both `U` and `V` should be orthonormal. In linear algebraic terms this separates the linear transformation `Y` into two "rotation" components and the central eigenvalue scaling component.

Since `S` is diagonal, we extract that diagonal as a vector using `diag(S)` and then subtract a term `tau` which must also be a vector. This *might* produce a diagonal containing negative values which cannot be properly interpreted as eigenvalues, so `pos` is there to trim out the negative eigenvalues, setting them to 0. We then use `diag` to convert the resulting vector back into a diagonal matrix and multiply the pieces back together to get `A`, a modified form of `Y`.

Note that we can skip some steps in Haskell as `svd` (and its "economy-sized" partner `thinSVD`) return vectors of eigenvalues instead of mostly 0'd diagonal matrices.

```
(u, s, v) = thinSVD y

-- note the trans here, that was the ' in Matlab
a = u `multiply` diag (fmap (max 0) s) `multiply` trans v
```

Above `fmap` maps `max 0` over the `Vector` of eigenvalues `s` and then `diag` (from `Numeric.Container`) reinflates the `Vector` into a `Matrix` prior to the `multiply`s. With a little thought it's easy to see that `max 0` is just `pos` applied to a single element.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use the second definition with the fmap' from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278221/how-do-you-make-a-functor-instance-of-matrix-and-vector-from-hmatrix-library Also thanks for pointing out the transpose that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

(A>0) returns the positions of elements of A which are larger than zero,
so forexample, if you have

```
A = [ -1 2 -3 4
       5 6 -7 -8 ]
```

then `B = (A > 0)` returns

```
B = [ 0 1 0 1
      1 1 0 0]
```

Note that we have ones corresponding to an elemnt of `A` which is larger than zero, and 0 otherwise.

Now if you multiply this elementwise with `A` using the `.*` notation, then you are multipling each element of `A` that is larger than zero with 1, and with zero otherwise. That is, `A .* B` means

```
[ -1*0   2*1   -3*0   4*1
   5*1   6*1   -7*0  -8*0 ]
```

giving finally,

```
[ 0 2 0 4
  5 6 0 0 ]
```

So you need to write your own function that will return positive values intact, and negative values set to zero.

And also, `u` and `v` does not match in dimension, for a generall SVD decomposition, so you actually would need to REDIAGONALIZE pos(diagS - Tau), so that `u* diagnonalized_(diagS -tau)` agrres to `v`

Comment: i found the introduction to hmatrix by Alberto Ruiz very useful (it has a list of command translations between haskell and matlab)